# "Stare" vs "essere" to express feelings or attitudes

Tags: word-usage, verbs, difference, synonym

Could both "essere" and "stare" be used with feelings (eg happy, calm) and attitudes (eg silent)?

It seems to me that yes. On the one hand, "stare" is used in sentences in imperative mood, ordering/suggesting a change of feeling/attitude. On the other hand, "essere" is used in statements, describing a current/permanent feeling/attitude. Examples:

Stai calmo/zitto/felice! = Be calm/silent/happy! (requests a change of mood)

Sei calmo/zitto/felice = You are calm/silent/happy (current/permanent state)

Is that right?

I am especially not sure about "essere" always being used with statements with feelings/attitudes. https://langsandlit.tumblr.com/post/161368437468/essere-we-use-essere-to-express says that "essere" is used with permanent state and "stare" with current state in this case, but I do not know if that is standard Italian.

Comment: «"essere" is used with permanent state and "stare" with current state in this case, but I do not know if that is standard Italian»: it is only in a limited range of situations. If anything, as an explanation it looks more similar to what happens in Spanish with _ser_ and _estar_. Is that correct, @Charo?

Comment: @DaG: Respect to feelings or attitudes is that way, but in general things are more complicated (see, for instance, [this](https://books.google.es/books?id=1muBAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA65)).

Comment: I think it's a difficult question because one says, for instance, "sto male", but "sono stanca", "sono innamorata", "sono preoccupata"...

Comment: Thanks, @Charo!

Comment: As a very broad rule of the thumb, you'd be rarely wrong by using _essere_, while _stare_ is far more delicate and used idiomatically. Many of the examples of _stare_ in the blog post you quote, correct as they are, would tolerate _essere_ as well (_Saro è tranquillo anche quando è solo_ and so on), while “the way someone is feeling or behaving right at that moment” only in particular, almost fixed, cases can be expressed with _stare_ (see Charo's examples: you say _sono stanca_, _sono innamorata_..., while it would be incorrect, or very local, to say _sto innamorata_ etc.).

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to have a look at [dictionary entry "stare"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/stare) to see in which kind of expressions one uses "stare" instead of "essere".

Comment: "innamorato" is an adjective which expresses a feeling, just as "calmo" and "felice". If "sto innamorato" is never used in standard Italian, my theory about using stare/essere for temporary/permanent states of feelings is not valid. Thanks for the example! I assume that one must learn case by case then. What about sentences in the imperative mood? Are they really only used with "stare"?

Comment: I have seen online Italian teachers say that the Italian verbs "stare/essere" work as the Spanish verbs "estar/ser" and it is a very unfortunate and confusing comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Both "essere" and "stare" can be used with feelings;

however, it depends on the feeling / attitude;

**imperative**

*stare*

- Stai calmo! - ok
- Stai zitto! - ok
- Stai felice! - it can sound like a joke (you can't order to
  be instantly happy); it's better    "Sii felice!" (literally be
  happy!) - this confirms that "stare" is    more tied to the current
  instant
- Stai bene! - can be used, to say    "come on, try to be fine!" -
  "bene" is adverb, not adjective)

*essere*

- Sii calmo! - ok - sounds kinder than "Stai calmo!"
- Sii zitto! - never heard
- Sii felice! - perfect
- Sii bene! - error

**present**

*stare*

- Tu stai calmo. (in this moment, I can see that "you are calm.")
- Tu stai zitto. (in this moment, I can see that "you are silent.")
- Tu stai felice. (in this moment, I can see that "you are happy")
- Tu stai bene. (in this moment, I can see that "you are fine")

*essere*

- Tu sei calmo. - ok - you are calm in this period or in this moment or
  by nature
- Tu sei zitto. - mmh - I would say "Tu sei in silenzio."
- Tu sei felice. - ok - you are happy in this period or in this moment
  or by nature
- Tu sei bene. - error

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE and thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I wouldn't want to suggest a polytical interpretation... but in this analysis I fell I miss "Stai sereno"